# Erro ao instalar phonegap pelo npm

Tags: node.js, apache-cordova, npm

Este é o problema que tem ocorrido, tentei instalar o gyp e não resolveu, alguém saberia me explicar o que esta ocorrendo por favor.

```
ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderrror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gup (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild) else (node rebuild)

ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderrror.log) || (exit 0)

C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine-io-cliente\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gup (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild) else (node rebuild)

C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\phonegap -> C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro da versão 0.10 do node.js:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-1.0.2.tgz

ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderrror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gup (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild) else (node rebuild)

ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderrror.log) || (exit 0)

C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine-io-cliente\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gup (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild) 

npm ERR! Error: EBUSY, open 'C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\phonegap-build\packge.json
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this "entire" log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at
npm ERR! <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Laris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\phonegap-build\package.json
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! errno 10
npm ERR! no ok code 0
```

Comment: Cole na sua pergunta o texto do erro que fica mais fácil de visualizar.

Comment: Editei. Erro escrito.

Comment: @LarissaMourullo, nodejs v4 é muito recente, pode ser que o Cordova ou Phonegap não ajustaram ainda suas dependência para esta versão. Tente desinstalar a versão atual e instalar a versão 0.8 ou 0.10. Depois nos diga o que ocorreu.

Comment: O erro na instalação do phonegap piorou com a a versão 0.10. Irei colocar o erro abaixo da imagem do antigo.

Comment: Tentei utilizar a versão 0.8 mais ai até o cordova não instala, dando milhões de erros e informando que precisa ser uma versão superior que a 0.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```